# Using Spark to Read from Hive

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, hive

#### Problem

I am attempting to read from a Hive table, but am receiving the following error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: tags; line 1 pos 14
```

I have placed `hive-site.xml` in both `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and `$HIVE_HOME/conf`. As well, I had no trouble using sqoop to grab the data from mysql and importing it into hive. Is something wrong with my Scala code? Or is this a config error?

#### Scala Code:

```
package test1

import java.io.File
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Movie(movieid: String, title: String, genres: String)
case class Tag(userid: String, title: String, tag: String)

object SparkHiveTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath
        val spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("SparkHiveExample")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate()

        spark.sql("SELECT * FROM tags").show()                      
        spark.stop()
    }
}
```

#### hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

   <property>

      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>

      <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>

   </property>

   <property>

      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>

      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>

      <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>

   </property>

   <property>

      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>

      <value>hiveuser</value>

      <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>

   </property>

   <property>

      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>

      <value>hivepass</value>

      <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>

   </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Hive metastore is configured properly:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>HIVE METASTORE URI(S) HERE</value>
    <description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Appended the above to my `hive-site.xml` file but ended up with the same result. I used `thrift://localhost:3306` as my URI (MySQL is local and I just used the default port).

Comment: Then assuming the URI is right, make sure you have all the Hive jars in the runtime classpath. I've seen cases where exceptions get swallowed causing things to fail silently.

Comment: Building this via .sbt. The hive library dependency is added w/ `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" %% "2.1.0"` - thought I would be set on the dependency jars.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API Document for [HiveContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html):

*An instance of the Spark SQL execution engine that integrates with data stored in Hive.* ***Configuration for Hive is read from hive-site.xml on the classpath.***

Therefore, be sure to put your `hive-site.xml` into the resource folder of your project in your IDE.

It solved my problem immediately.